# Notating Microtonal Chords

Tags: notation, chords, microtonality

Normally, when notating chords, I would use the sharp and flat symbols, and it stands to reason that for chords with quarter tones, I would use demisharp, demiflat, and whatnot. However, if I want to note that one (or more) notes in a chord is, say, 33 cents flat, how would I notate that.

Example chord I want to notate: E augmented but the C (or B#) is 33 cents sharp. How would that work in chord notation?